# I want to sort a file for lines not containing a digit

Tags: regex, linux, sorting

I have a file containing lines of mixed strings, for example, peaches, twelve, twelve_peaches, 12_peaches, and 12peaches. 
I want to sort out only the lines that do not contain digits, like, peaches, twelve, twelve_peaches. 
I'm using vim in Linux.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52018073/edit) and add an extract of the file you want to sort and expected result.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score -1):

If you rely on vi only maybe you can benefit from regular expressions and grep.

The lines you are dealing with:

```
peaches, twelve, twelve_peaches, 12_peaches, and 12peaches
peaches, twelve, twelve_peaches
```

By using:

```
:g!/[[:digit:]]
```

Result:

```
peaches, twelve, twelve_peaches
```

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to sort the file so that I can direct the output to another file.